# Update a JSON column in mysql using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, updating

I am using sequelize with mysql and i am trying to update a column which is of JSON type. I specifically want to update a particular key in the JSON. Here is what I have tried till now.

```
Profile.update(
        values,
      {
        where: {
          id : id
       }
    }).then(function(obj) {
       ...
    }.catch(function(err){
       ...
    })
```

It removes the entire value and updates the new value. I want to just update that particular key alone. The content of `values` is,

```
{
    "details"{ 
        name : "user"
    }
}
```

`details` is the field i want to update and `name` is the key to update. I couldn't find any helpful resource for this with sequelize. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go through this link https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4387